# wxpython prevent panel overwriting MDIChildFrame

Tags: wxpython

Windows 10 - I have adapted some example code from here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/MDIframe.htm to add a panel to the MDIClientWindow but whenever I open one of the MDIChildFrames from the menu it immediately gets drawn over by the panel.

If I change the code to put the panel in the MDIParentFrame (panel = wx.Panel(self, size = (100,100)) then the MDIChildFrame overdraws the panel plus I noticed that the panel gets no events (presumably the MDIClientWindow has grabbed them).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
import wx
#import wx.lib.inspection


class MDIFrame(wx.MDIParentFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.MDIParentFrame.__init__(self, None, -1, "MDI Parent",size=(600,400))
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(5000, "&New Window")
        menu.Append(5001, "E&xit")
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(menu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnNewWindow, id=5000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=5001)

        panel = wx.Panel(self.GetClientWindow(), size = (100,100))

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnNewWindow(self, evt):
        win = wx.MDIChildFrame(self, -1, "Child Window")
        win.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
frame = MDIFrame()
frame.Show()
#wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have no access to a Microsoft OS but given that internally an MDI child frame is a child of the MDI client window, in wxWidgets you create it as a child of wx.MDIParentFrame, have you tried making the `panel` a child of `self` NOT the `wx.MDIClientWindow`. My other thought, is perhaps the `panel` needs to be in its own `wx.MDIChildFrame`. As I said, I can't test this but give it a whirl.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried making the panel a child of the MDIParentFrame, as mentioned above, this then has the opposite effect (child frame overwrites panel) plus no events go to the panel. I will try your second suggestion and report back.

Comment: I tried putting the panel in it's own MDIChildFrame, this prevented other child frames being overwritten but the panel itself did not draw correctly in it's MDIChildFrame (border did not work, background colour filled the parent frame). After allot of experiments I am abandoning MDI frames as broken, at least on windows. Any hints on how else to get windows contained in a window using wxpython?

Comment: Simply, declare as many `wx.Panel` in a normal `wx.Frame` as you require, arranging them in an appropriate `sizer` and you're good to go.

Comment: Rolf - Was specifically after the "Frame contained in Frame" functionality that a normal Frame does not supply, MDI frames do this and it looks like Windows may have stopped supporting them (MS did warn this was going to happen).